# initialize then output in single line

Tags: php, c++

**PHP**

```
<?php 
    $x = 10; 
    echo $x = 20;
?>
```

**c++**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int x = 10;

    cout << x = 20;

    return 0;

}
```

Why in php initialize then ouput in a single line works, in c++ it didnt work?

Comment: echo $x = 20; <-- this is what i mean

Answer (score 1):

- this: `cout << x = 20;` is *not* initialization. Initialization is assigning the initial value to a variable, so in your case it is done in the first string: `int x = 10;`.
- you have 2 lines in PhP, not one.
- what happens in C++ happens because of operator precedence.

Operator precedence is basically in what order operators shuold be executed. It's like in math where `*` and `/` happen before `+` and `-`.

`operator<<` in C++ has higher precedence than `operator=`, so it will be executed first, and only then the `operator=` will take place.

[Operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 0):

because precedence of operators differ.

"Precedence of operators is something that we sometimes take for granted, particularly if we are thoroughly familiar and comfortable with the standard precedence rules for the common arithmetic operators. But being too complaisant can put us at some peril, and particularly in a language like C++, which has such a variety of operators, it pays to be on our guard.

As a brief example, note from the table that the input/output operators (>> and <<) have a higher precedence than the relational operators but a lower precedence than the arithmetic operators. This means that a statement like"

http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/ref/cpp_operators.html

---

your c++ code won't  compile at all throwing:

```
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:6:17: error: no match for 'operator=' in 'std::cout.std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>](x) = 20'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/iosfwd:86:11: note: candidate is: std::basic_ostream<char>& std::basic_ostream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ostream<char>&)
```

you have to enclose your code in brackets to have it compile. when you do so, you will get the same output as for php.

Answer (score 0):

It *does* work

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std;  

int main(){
      int x = 10;
      cout << (x = 20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprized that it compiles for you because `std::cout << x = 20` ; is the same as `( std::cout << x ) = 20`, and the result of `std::cout << x` is not a left value. If you desire, however such initialization, which is a bad idea anyway, you can do `std::cout << ( x = 20 )`. Please don't do it however. It makes difficult to read the source, and it does not improve performance anyway. Such simple optimization are now done by compilers.